# reordenar array java

Tags: java, array

Buenas, 
Tengo dos clases en java una llamada Kart y otr CarreraKart donde simula una carrera. Me gustaria mostrar en el array que saco por pantalla la clasificacion ya ordenada cuando adelantan. El metodo reodenar tiene que ser asi es el que no consigo sacar en adelante

Esta es la clase principal CarreraKarts

```
package carrerakarts;


public class CarreraKarts {

public static void verClasificacion(int[] p) {

    int[] a = p;

    System.out.print("CLASIF.: (" + p[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < p.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("," + a[i]);
    }
    System.out.print(" )\n");

}

public static int verPos(int[] p, int numero) {

    return 1;
}

public static void reordenar(int[] p, int numero, int adelanta) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        // Recorrer desde la siguiente posición en adelante para comparar
        // el elemento en la posición conta con los de más adelante
        for (int j = i + 1; j < p.length; j++) {
            // Si el elemento inicial es mayor lo intercambiamos
            if (p[j] < p[i]) {
                adelanta = p[i];
                p[i] = p[j];
                p[j] = adelanta;
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ------- DECLARACIONES E INICIALIZACIONES
    // Declarar arrays de objetos
    Kart[] kart = new Kart[10];
    // Declarar array de posiciones
    // El coche nº 10 lo poenmos en posición 1, el 9 en la 2, ...
    int[] posicion = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    // Variable que registra adelantamientos
    int adelantamiento = 0;
    // Instanciar objetos
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        kart[i] = new Kart(i + 1, 40 + i);
    }
    // Ver propiedades de los objetos
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(kart[i]);
    }
    // --------------------------
    // Ver clasificación actual
    verClasificacion(posicion);
    // Dar una vuelta para todos los kart       
    for (int v = 0; v < 6; v++) {
        System.out.println("))))) VUELTA: " + v);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Inicio de la vuelta del coche " + kart[i].numero);
            adelantamiento = kart[i].vuelta();
            if ((adelantamiento != 0) && (verPos(posicion, kart[i].numero) - adelantamiento) >= 0) {
                reordenar(posicion, kart[i].numero, adelantamiento);
                System.out.println("El coche " + kart[i].numero + " tiene un premio por adelantar");
            }
        }
        // Ver clasificación actual
        verClasificacion(posicion);
    }
    // Ver propiedades de los objetos
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(kart[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Dejo la clase Karts.

```
package carrerakarts;


public class Kart {

int numero;
int deposito;
int velocidad;

public Kart(int numero, int velocidad) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.velocidad = velocidad;
    this.deposito = 30;
}

public int getDeposito() {
    return deposito;
}

public int getVelocidad() {
    return velocidad;
}

public boolean depositoVacio() {
    if(this.deposito<=0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

public int vuelta() {
    int adelanta = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
    if(adelanta <= 1);
    return adelanta; 
}

public String toString() {
    return "** Coche nº"+this.numero+" ** Dep."+this.getDeposito()+" ** vel."+this.getVelocidad();
}
}
```

Comment: Que has intentado para el método reordenar? que le vas a pasar, el vector de los karts, el kart que adelanta y cuantas posiciones adelanta???

Comment: Buenas el kart adelanta una posicion es decir, el vector de los karts seria, int[] posicion = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};   y si el coche 9 adelanta al 10 sera 9 , 10, 8, 7 .... y asi gracias

Comment: que has probado? Hace falta ver tu código para ver en que te has equivocado y arreglarlo. Una cosa, si vas a llamar al método cada vez que un coche adelante creo que no hace falta la posición, simplemente el array y el coche que adelanta puesto que siempre va a adelantar una posición.

Comment: Buenas ya modifique el codigo e hice eso pero claro eso ordena el array por completo cambia todas las posiciones...

Comment: si, lo que haces con ese código es una ordenación de mayor a menor (o al revés), no intercambias sólo un valor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar una sola posición es simplemente un cambio de valor entre 2 variables. Se haría así:

```
//Le vamos a pasar por ejemplo que el kart en la posicion 2 adelanta un puesto
public static void reordenar(int[] p, int numero) { //Siendo p[] el array de posiciones y numero la posición del kart que adelanta
    //Tenemos que p = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] y posicion = 2

    int aux = p[numero]; //Guardamos el que adelanta en una variable auxiliar
    //En aux guardamos el número 8

    p[numero] = p[numero-1];
    //Sobreescribimos esa posición con el valor anterior, quedaría así el array
    //p = [10,9,9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];

    p[numero - 1] = aux;
    //Sobreescribimos en la posición numero-1 el valor que habíamos guardado
    // Queda así p = [10,8,9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1];
}
```

Tienes que asegurarte que no le vas a pasar un 0 a la función en el parámetro numero aunque no debería ser posible ya que el que vaya en primera posición nunca va a adelantar.

Comment: Vale entiendo, la cosa es que adelanta no se lo pasa no? es decir ahi no cambia la posicion del que adelanta.

Comment: igual estoy equivocado pero como te he comentado antes creo que no hace falta ya que cada kart sólo adelanta de 1 en 1

Comment: Vale entiendo, voy a probar creo que por ese camino puedo sacar la solucion. Muchas gracias